# tikzpicture across pages

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw a border to the left for each page. As you see in the screenshot it doesn't seem to follow to the second page. I have this simple command at the beginning of my document

```
%BORDER
\tikzset{background/.style={fill=backgroundColor}}
%\tikzset{background grid/.style = {thick, draw  = red, step = .5cm}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
       \draw [style=background, xshift=-2.5cm, yshift=2cm, very thin] (0mm,-290mm) rectangle (20mm, 0mm); 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Tikz border]

## Edit

As per request here's a minimum working example, which displays two issues: border not spanning across pages, and padded from left. I'm posting it although the issue is solved, see accepted answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{mwe}

\definecolor{backgroundColor}{HTML}{CC3300}
\tikzset{background/.style={fill=backgroundColor}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
       \draw [style=background, xshift=-2.5cm, yshift=3cm, very thin] (0mm,-290mm) rectangle (20mm, 0mm); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a complete minimal working example? Also, did you look at the **[background](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/background)** package for drawing stuff on every page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the background key in TikZ refers to specific nodes, pics, graphs etc., not the page.  For that you would need the everypage or background package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{mwe}

\AddEverypageHook{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \fill[red] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page text area.west |- current page.north);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```